# Building DataFrame with column names contained in a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have this [csv file](https://data.open-power-system-data.org/time_series/2019-06-05/time_series_30min_stacked.csv) (downloaded from [here](https://data.open-power-system-data.org/time_series/2019-06-05), open 'alternative formats' and chose 'stacked' one).

When opened, it contains something like this:

[image]

As you see, in the column 'variable' there are multiple names. I would like to move each variable type to a new column, using 'None' if not available so that the result is:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
| country | timestamp | load_load | wind_generation | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
| DE      | 2013      | 165.9     | None            | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
| IT      | 2014      | 143.8     | 123.4           | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
```

I use python 3.6 and, if needed, pandas.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you want to do: make sure your column "utc_timestamp" is in a datetime format. You can then easily group per year, month, ... whatever you want. It is not clear from the question, but I suppose you want to group the data per year, region and "variable", and get the mean value per group. So do a simple groupby, including the pd.grouper function. Next, use the unstack command on "variable", this will put the different values in the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('time_series_30min_stacked.csv')

df["utc_timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["utc_timestamp"])
df_perYear = df.groupby(["region", "variable", pd.Grouper(key='utc_timestamp', freq="Y")]).mean()["data"]
df_unstack = df_perYear.unstack("variable")
```

Comment: Yep, except that I don't want the "mean()" but raw results...

Comment: If you want the results per region/variable/timestamp, you could to the following `df_group = df.groupby(["region", "variable", "utc_timestamp"])["data"].sum()` and
`df_unstack = df_group.unstack("variable")`